# Additive like function representation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Let's $f:R\rightarrow R,~r\gt0.$ And we have that for every $x,y\in R\Rightarrow |f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)|\le r.$ Prove that there are $h:R \rightarrow R$ additive and $g:R \rightarrow [-r,r]$ functions such that $$f(x)=g(x)+h(x).$$
I have no idea how I can approach this problem.

Comment: Once you have the homomorphism $h\colon (\mathbb{R},+) \to (\mathbb{R},+)$, obviously setting $g = f-h$ finishes it.

Comment: But why will $g=f-h$ necessarily have range in $[-r,r]$?